# Different output when running a query in SSMS and SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a DFT that transfers data from OLEDB Source to OLEDB destination. The Source has a query that has the below CASE statement:

```
SELECT Case Gender
            When 'M' Then 'M'
            When 'F' Then 'F'
            Else Case XX_GenderID
                   When 1 Then 'M'   
                   When 5 Then 'F'   
                   Else 'U' 
                   End
            End as IN_Gender
FROM TblA
```

When I run the DFT in SSIS it SOMETIMES changes the INCOMING 'U' value from TblA to '9' in the destination. I have no idea where this 9 is coming from. But when I test this query in SSMS, it did NOT convert the U to 9. I also tried executing just that step manually in the SSIS and it still did NOT convert the U value. I have no idea as to what might be causing this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a data type issue, you might try an explicit cast to CHAR(1) in the query:

```
SELECT CAST(Case Gender ...
End AS CHAR(1)) as IN_Gender
FROM TblA
```

I would try adding [Data Viewers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140318.aspx) to your data flow at various steps.  If the value is getting changed to 9 later on, you can see where that is happening.  If it is already 9 coming out of the data source, then you know that's where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If you have seemingly random data changes then something else is changing it. A trigger? another SSIS? another stored procedure? Some code in your SSIS that you didn't notice?